# How to Promise.all for nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

Structure of the data:

```
tasks: [
  {
    name: "get milk",
    users: ["abc", "def"]
  },
  {
    name: "buy bread",
    users: ["def", "ghi"]
  }
]
```

I need to get the email address of each one of the users from the database (so far so good) and wait for all tasks to be completed, then move on and do something with the data. The place where it doesn't work is written in the comments below:

```
var tasks_with_emails = tasks.map(function(task) {
  var emails = task.users.map(function(user) {
    return user_to_email(user); // from the database
  });
  Promise.all(emails).then(function(emails) {
    task.emails = emails;
    console.log(task); // this one works fine
    return task;
  }).catch(next);
});
Promise.all(tasks_with_emails).then(function(tasks) {
  console.log(tasks); // <==== this one fires too quickly
}).catch(next);
```

So `tasks_with_email` should wait for all nested `emails` to resolve first, but it doesn't.

Comment: I believe you are missing a return statement for `Promise.all(emails)`. Try adding a return in front of Promise.all(email)

Comment: `tasks_with_emails` is an array full of `undefined`s

Comment: Since you don't return the `Promise.all()` from inside `tasks_with_emails`, as Oleksii points out, `Promise.all(tasks_with_emails)` immediately resolves, since `tasks_with_emails` is an array that does not contain any promises.

Comment: @OleksiiRudenko just tried, same result: `tasks_with_emails` is an array of 2 `null`

Comment: @trs maybe try extracting the function inside of ```tasks.map``` to a named function and see if it's failing there. You're returning ```task``` inside the ```Promise.all``` but it may be failing, in which case you want to return ```tasks``` without the email at the least.

Comment: Don't do `.catch(next)` inside the loop. I'm certain `next` is expected to be called at most once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the return in front of `Promise.all()`, your code works for me, as you can see in the below example.
So have a look at what `user_to_email()` returns. This should be a promise that resolves into the email string.

```js
const user_to_email = user => new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve( `${ user }@example.com` ), 3000 );
});
const tasks  = [
  {
  name: "get milk",
  users: ["abc", "def"]
  },
  {
  name: "buy bread",
  users: ["def", "ghi"]
  }
];
const tasks_with_emails = tasks.map( task => {
  const emails = task.users.map( user => {
    return user_to_email(user); // from the database
  });
  return Promise.all(emails).then( emails => {
    task.emails = emails;
    return task;
  });
});
Promise.all(tasks_with_emails).then( tasks => {
  console.log(tasks); // <==== this one fires too quickly
});
setTimeout(() => console.log( '1000ms' ), 1000 );
setTimeout(() => console.log( '2000ms' ), 2000 );
setTimeout(() => console.log( '2999ms' ), 2999 );
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was somewhere else completely, but adding return in front of Promise.all() does indeed solve it. Thanks.